# How to attach library sources using intelliJ in gradle project so that I can edit library classes?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How to attach library sources using intelliJ in gradle project so that I can
edit library classes?

Comment: If you plan to edit the classes from the library, composite builds is the way to go: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add external library's sources and javadoc to gradle with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765193/how-to-add-external-librarys-sources-and-javadoc-to-gradle-with-intellij)